# add_action hook for links.php page

Tags: hooks, links

What is the definite hook which identifies links.php page (add, edit, delete, etc.  Blogroll Links), and only this page?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
cadeyrn

EDIT

Sorry, I forgot to mention, I need this hook in the admin area. I have a plugin, that brakes an other one, because both are triggered by the admin_menu add_action. Therefore I need an add_action point that is only valid for the admin menu's link edit/add/delete part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I made an awful, but working solution: the hook is `admin_menu`, than, in the called function, I added

```
if( strstr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'link.php')
```

in the begining.

If there's a better solution, please someone send it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the (public) wp template hierarchy there's no `links.php` file expected. Links are a built in taxonomy, so I (guess) it's `if ( is_archive( 'link_category' ) ) /* do stuff */`.

Or are you talking about admin pages?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific, yes, I did mean the admin pages.

Comment: The only hook i know is the `admin_menu` hook itself. From a brief look at `/wp-root/wp-admin/link-manager.php` i couldn't find any hooks, so i guess you'll have to rely on those mentioned in the action API/reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Oh, and you could still use priority with the hook to avoid collisions: `add_action( 'admin_menu', 'some_action', 30  )`.

Answer (score 0):

Hook for what exactly?

And in any case it is easy to use any hook and check if you are at the right page. For example by comparing global `$hook_suffix` variable to `link-manager.php` (there is no `links.php` by the way). There is also block of dynamic hooks that rely on this variable in [`admin-header.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.1/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L75).